# Excel formula to check on date falls within a range

Tags: microsoft-excel

Anyone could help with a formula to check if any of the receipt date in 1st excel falls within the multiple range of dates in 2nd excel?

1st excel shows:

Column A, Names - row 1 to 5 in order ABC, ABC, ABC, DEF, DEF.

Column B, Receipt date - row 1 to 5 in order 05/01/2018, 02/03/2018, 06/03/2018, 16/04/2018, 10/05/2018.

2nd excel shows:

Column A, Names - row 1 to 5 in order ABC, ABC, DEF, DEF, DEF.

Column B, Leave Start date - row 1 to 5 in order 01/01/2018, 01/03/2018, 01/03/2018, 15/04/2018, 01/05/2018.

Column C, Leave End date - row 1 to 5 in order 01/02/2018, 15/03/2018, 10/03/2018, 16/04/2018, 15/05/2018.

Comment: Better you share sample data with us since your question is quite confusing,,,, especially this one,,`The only common column is column a (name list).` ☺

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Wasnt able to add picture in my browser. Anyway I have amended my question and added the columns info. Hopefully better, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

*I'm assuming that `Excel 1` is `Sheet 1` and `Excel 2` is `Sheet 2`.*

[image]

**How it works:**

1. **Write following formula in Sheet 2:**

   To get `Earliest Date`, in Cell `I132`.

   ```
   =Min(K125:L129)
   ```

   For `Latest Date` in Cell `J132` write this.

   ```
   =Max(K125:L129)
   ```
2. Enter this Formula in cell `G132`.

   ```
    =SUMPRODUCT((Sheet1!$H$125:$H$129>=I132)*(Sheet1!$H$125:$H$129<=J132))
   ```
3. Write this Array Formula in Cell `G135`, finish with `Ctrl+Shift+Enter` & fill down.

`{=IF(ROWS(G$135:G135)>$G$132,"",INDEX(Sheet1!H$125:H$129,SMALL(IF((Sheet1!$H$125:$H$129>=$I$132)*(Sheet1!$H$125:$H$129<=$J$132),ROW(Sheet1!H$125:H$129)-ROW(Sheet1!$H$125)+1),ROWS(G$135:G135))))}`

**Note,** *adjust Sheet Name & Cell references in the Formula as needed.*

Comment: Thanks for replying. I like to have yes or no answer in column I row 125 onwards if the date in column H falls within the start date in column K and end date in column L for that specific name. Can it be done?

Comment: @Ris,, nothing is impossible but the question is what was the original problem you have posted? I've solved the issue on that basis only. If after that you make twist in question will create problem since it's time taking job,,, my simple suggestion is since  my method has extracted date falls withing dates then first accept it,,, and after that edit the question and post the new one !!